# Automatizing Chrome's "save as pdf" feature

Tags: c#, google-chrome, pdf, asp.net-web-api, pdf-generation

I would like to enable users to save pages of my app as PDF files.

I spent the entire day trying the different API's available online but in all of them the (fairly complex angular) pages look horrible. I could spend a week fixing up custom CSS but Chrome's PDF printouts seem perfect.

Is there *any* way to have my (ASP.NET) server or even client machines use whatever it is chrome is using?

Comment: Did you find any solution ? Can we access to Chrome's pdf feature ?

Comment: @osayilgan sadly I couldn't find one, used phantomjs' `render` instead